# How to detect what button was clicked? (Pynput)

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to detect  what mouse button was clicked

so here is my code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_click(button, pressed):
   if button.Left and pressed:
       print("You pressed the left mouse button")
   if button.Right and pressed:
       print("You pressed the right mouse button")
```

so there was no errors but It's not working any Ideas?

Comment: Is visible that you are importing from a Package called pynput, however in the question you should be more explicit regarding what framework you are using

Comment: First, you don't attach the listener. Second, the parameters are `x, y, button, pressed` (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Documentation [Here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse)

### CODE

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(button)  # Print button to see which button of mouse was pressed
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    



# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click
       ) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
```

As you can see, the `button` parameter in the function `on_click` tells you which button was pressed.

> EDIT:

Here is how you may handle action based on which button of the mouse was pressed

```
 def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    btn = button.name

    if btn == 'left':
        print('Left if Pressed')
        # ====== < Handle Pressed or released Event ====== > # 
        if pressed:
            print('Do somethin when Pressed with LEft')
        else:
            print('LEFT is Released')
    elif btn == 'right':
        print('Right BTN was pressed ')
        # ====== < Handle Pressed or released Event ====== > # 
        if not pressed:
            print('right Button is released')
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Hey thanks but how can I check if it pressed or realesed?

Comment: I edited the answer, just use the pressed parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding but I'm getting an error and I can't fix it, here is my code

Comment: The code
```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import mouse
import time
import random
mouse = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    btn = button.name
    if btn == 'left':
        if pressed:
                mouse.click(Button.left)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01,0.05))
                mouse.click(Button.left)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.055,0.095))

with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click
       ) as listener:
    listener.join()
 ```

Comment: from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller from pynput import mouse import time import random mouse = Controller() def on_click(x, y, button, pressed): btn = button.name if btn == 'left': if pressed: mouse.click(Button.left) time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01,0.05)) mouse.click(Button.left) time.sleep(random.uniform(0.055,0.095)) with mouse.Listener( on_click=on_click ) as listener: listener.join()

Comment: I used you code but It's not working it says 'Controller' object has no attribute 'Listener'

Comment: I see that you did `from pynput.mouse import Button`and is not `from pynput import mouse`. if you copy and paste my same excact code it should work

Comment: from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput import mouse
import time
import random


mouse = Controller()


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    btn = button.name

    if btn == 'left':
        if pressed:
                mouse.click(Button.left)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.01,0.05))
                mouse.click(Button.left)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(0.055,0.095))
    



with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click
       ) as listener:
    listener.join()

Comment: not working copy and paste my code and you will see

Comment: @commandot tv il  don't add the code in a comment, is impossible to read, Edit you question with the Excact code you are using

Comment: You can Edit your own questions, so go  and edit it and add the code you are using (the one I wrote)

Comment: Anyway I see, you use= from pynput.mouse import Controller   it should be `from pynput import mouse`

Comment: is not my code because is different, and has got errors..

Comment: not working it says "name 'Controller' is not defined"

Comment: I added another answer so that are separete, you make mistakes when importing. Also to note, running `mouse_.click(button_.left) ` make my PC very slow, so be careful to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I post a second answer because of a different nature of the issue found on code [here](http://pastebin.com/0CD7r2HY)

The issue is how you call the imports.

### CORRET CODE

```
from pynput import mouse


mouse_ = mouse.Controller()
button = mouse.Button

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    btn = button.name

    if btn == 'left':
        if pressed:
            mouse_.click(button_.left)
            print('works')


with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Copy and Paste the code without changes.

**WARNING**

when I use `button.left` my pc becomes extremely lagy so i suggest you to don't use is unless you know what you are doing